# Struck with receive() and fallback() error. TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address"

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, fallback-function, receive

I am new to solidity, learning smart contract development. I got stuck while I was learning about the fallback function. This function throws an error saying "TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address" ". I did search about this on solidity documents but I can't understand the issue. In some places I found that on the new update we have to use the **receive** function when there is **no argument**, mutability is **payable**, should not return anything and the visibility must be **external**. I tried with the receive function but there is no luck.

Can someone please help me understand what is the problem here and how to solve this?

```
fallback() external payable {   
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}   //At first I tried this function

receive() external payable {   
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
}  //Since the fallback() threw error I tried this function but it still shows the same error.
```

Comment: As I just explained here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112269/error-transact-to-lottery-receive-errored-vm-error-revert/112272#112272

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful. I thought the problem was with the receive() and fallback() but the real issue was with payable(msg.sender).